# Get Tabs URL, copy to new tab, change something in domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Basically I just want to check links across different environments and thats just a different domain name. So basically I have my extension so far with buttons for each one but am having trouble getting anything to happen. Tried in b ackground.js as I thought that was the only place to access tab?

Tried this and some other variations but yeah this is very new to me so forgive my ignorance. I know javascript well enough but this is taking a bit to adjust.

```
let dev = document.getElementByID("dev");
console.log(dev);
dev.onclick = function(element) {
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
     chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "www.google.com"});
});
```

Comment: 1) An URL must start with a scheme: `https://www.google.com`. 2) Make sure to read about the extensions [overview::architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) - the popup is a separate page with its own window, URL, and devtools which you can access by rightclicking the popup, then clicking Inspect. 3) Hint: no need to use tabs.query to change the active tab - simply omit `tab.id, ` from tabs.update as it's an optional parameter.

Comment: Thanks I made your comment the answer. New to posting to stack so not sure if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) An URL must start with a scheme: https://www.google.com. 2) Make sure to read about the extensions overview::architecture - the popup is a separate page with its own window, URL, and devtools which you can access by rightclicking the popup, then clicking Inspect. 3) Hint: no need to use tabs.query to change the active tab - simply omit tab.id, from tabs.update as it's an optional parameter. – wOxxOm

Thanks that helped a lot!